# Can't acces DNS

Tags: centos, dns

I'm running CentOS as a Virtual Machine.
I can access the VM's server (IP = 192.168.0.107, which displays a phpinfo() page as it should), but now I would like to acces a custom domain name: "imd.be" and reach that same phpinfo() page. This has worked before but not anymore (on other router). Here's what I've done.

in resolv.conf

```
 nameserver 192.168.0.107
```

in named.conf

```
zone "imd.be" IN {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/imd.be.zone";
    };
```

in imd.be.zone

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                                    42              ; serial
                                    3600            ; refresh
                                    900             ; retry
                                    1W              ; expire
                                    1D )            ; minimum ttl voor cache
@                       NS              localhost.
                    A               192.168.0.107
www             A               192.168.0.107
ftp                     CNAME   www
admin           CNAME   www
jo              A               192.168.O.107
herexamen               CNAME   www
```

in /etc/httpd/conf.d/imd.be.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/imd.be
  ServerName imd.be
  ErrorLog logs/imd.be-error_log
  CustomLog logs/imd.be-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
dig imd.be
```

returns

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

What am I missing to browse imd.be and acces my own webpage?

Comment: Has all this configuration work been carried out on the CentOS machine or the VM host.  What OS/distro are you running on the host?

Comment: @Robbert Segers you should check if you can reach the port with `telnet`

Comment: What kind of logging are you doing on the `bind` side? Do the log files have anything useful around the times you submit your `dig` requests?

Comment: Is bind running? Does it resolve other queries?

Answer (score 0):

Well for connection timed out, it is most probably `netfilter/iptables` . You should provide an exception for port `53` with:-

```
iptables -A INPUT --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

This is just an example you should refine it accordingly for further security.

Comment: well my iptables are OFF. iptables -L returns anywhere anywhere everywhere..

Comment: @RobbertSegers alright and as I suggested in the previous comment did you check with `telnet`? Also it would be interesting to know what `allow-transfer {"";};` contains in your `named.conf`

Comment: your command isn't recognized. I did 'iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT' but telnet still returns connection refused

Comment: 'allow-transfer' is not in the file.. 'allow-query     { localhost; 0.0.0.0/0; };' is most similar

Comment: @RobbertSegers sorry didnt see `telnet` answer.

Comment: @RobbertSegers are you sure your `bind` is running. Try restarting the service and post the logs in your question.

Comment: 'service named start' works now, where is that log file? Or which one do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16249/discussion-between-robbert-segers-and-beginer).